# How can I update a field and set it to 'b' in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite as DB and when I try to set the name field to 'b' it just doesn't work and the name field remains NULL. When I try it with other values ('c' for example) it's completely OK but when I try it with 'b' this happens:
[image]

[image]

PS: I have the same problem when I try to update the database with python-sqlite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only 1 case that this could happen and it is if you have another column in the table with the name `b`.
In this case, the assignment:

```
name = "b"
```

interprets `"b"` as the value of the column `b` (because of the double quotes), which may be `null` and it assigns `null` to the column `name`.

Remove the double quotes from your code and use only single quotes for string literals:

```
update tests 
set name = 'b' 
where id = '6'; -- if id is integer use id = 6
```